# Jquery show div when link gets clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to show/hide a div using jquery when a link gets clicked. I put this in my head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $("#attach_box").click(function {
    $("#sec_box").show()
    });        
</script>
```

I have a link that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" id="attach_box">+ Add a Postal Address (If Different)</a>
```

And a div that looks like this:

```
<div id="sec_box" style="display: none;">
Hello world!!               
</div>
```

This doesn't work and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to attach the [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler in the [document.ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()) in order to make sure that the DOM has been loaded by the browser and all the elements are available:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(function() {
       $('#attach_box').click(function() {
           $('#sec_box').show();
           return false;
       });        
   });
</script>
```

Also you forgot to put parenthesis `()` next to the anonymous function in the `click` handler.

Comment: I'd also add `return false;` to the end of the function so that the # doesn't end up in the location, but that's just a personal preference.

Comment: That works beautifully. Any idea how I could go about hiding the div when the user clicks the link a second time?

Comment: @Thomas, yes, try `$('#sec_box').toggle();`

Answer (score 2):

Chances are the DOM isnt fully loaded yet.

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready(function()
      {  
         $("#attach_box").click(function() {
         $("#sec_box").show()
         });  
       });      
   </script>
```

put that in your head and put your initialization code in there.